# Updated wordpress missing image upload area

Tags: images, uploads, media, updates

Our wordpress updated yesterday. We are on version 5.3.2.

Since the update the upload files function within a page is blank.

I have included a screenshot, I wondered if anyone else has had this issue or knows how to resolve?

[image]

Comment: It's probably a Javascript conflict with some plugin ( or theme), try to deactivate them one by one and find the one it's causing it, switch to the default theme.  Also  inspect the javascript console of your browser that can give you some information about the errors

Comment: thanks very much!